# How to retrieve Oracle JSON_OBJECT in C#

Tags: c#, json, oracle12c

My first stab at getting data as array of JSON object from Oracle. I am not sure what I need to use after I setup the connection in my C# code and call the query to return the objects.

I can't use OrcalDataAdapater.Fill(some_dataset), it returns empty data table.
Not sure if I have use OracleDataReader and then loop through each row. I thought using Oracle JSON object would make it easier as I won't have to convert to JSON after fetching the data.

I just need to be sure I am doing this correctly and efficiently.

```
SELECT json_object(
'uniqueId'  VALUE REQUEST_ID,
'ip'  VALUE COMPUTER_EQUIPMENT_NAME,
'lclDtm'  VALUE REQ_TS,
'utcDtm'  VALUE UTC_TS,
'errorCode'  VALUE RESPONSE_ERROR_CODE
FORMAT JSON) AS JSON_STRING
FROM(
SELECT req.REQUEST_ID,  
to_char(req.REQUEST_TS, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS REQ_TS, to_char(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST (req.REQUEST_TS AS TIMESTAMP)), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS UTC_TS, 
resp.RESPONSE_ERROR_CODE, req.COMPUTER_EQUIPMENT_NAME
FROM TBL_REQUEST req 
INNER JOIN TBL_RESPONSE resp ON req.REQUEST_ID = resp.REQUEST_ID 
);
```

This returns an array of JSON objects.

**Update:**

I tried below to read the query result:

```
try
{
    dbContext.Open();
    spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("StartDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2, dtStartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), ParameterDirection.Input));
    spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("EndDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2, dtEndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), ParameterDirection.Input));
    OracleDataReader oraReader = default(OracleDataReader);
    dbContext.ExecuteReaderCmd(sQuery, spParams, ref oraReader);

    if (oraReader.Read())    // Returns "false"
    {
        if (oraReader["JSON_STRING"] != DBNull.Value)
            sErrors = oraReader["JSON_STRING"].ToString();
    }
    ...
}

public void ExecuteReaderCmd(string sQuery, List<OracleParameter> spParams, ref OracleDataReader dataReader)
{
    dataReader = default(OracleDataReader);

    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        if (spParams != null && spParams.Count() > 0) command.Parameters.AddRange(spParams.ToArray<OracleParameter>());
        command.Connection = DbConnection;
        command.CommandText = sQuery;
        command.BindByName = true;

        try
        {
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (OracleException oex)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a column alias.  Json_object returns varchar2(4000) so just a normal string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you. I added "as json_string" after "... FORMAT JSON)" and tried to get the data using ExecuteReader() but nothing is returned even though running the query in SQL Developer shows data. I updated the initial post.